# Is there any way to download a new browser, without the current (and only) one working?

Tags: windows-7, browser, download, virus

I have a very strange problem with IE, it somehow disappeared of the user's workstation. I detected a lot of infections, some malware and some worms. I definitely suspect the iexplore.exe being deleted or infected and /or removed by the anti-virus agent, since the error I am getting says `The specific path does not exist. Check the path and try again.` So what do I do now? I tried booting in safe mode as well, traced the internet explorer location, but no iexplore.exe found there. I also tried to get I.E reinstalled by installing windows updates, no sucess. So is there anyway to download another browser without access to a current browser? In worst case I can recommend an re-installation of Windows, but would like try to and fix the problem first. In Linux a way to do this would be something like `sudo apt-get install chrome-browser`,but fortunately Linux and virusses aren't friends.

Note: The workstation is troubleshooted over a remote connection, thus a copy of a browser on a flash is sort of difficult under the circumstances.

Comment: Can't you transfer the install file over the remote connection?

Comment: Already tried that, it failed due to a pretty lame connection -_-

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear.  If the system so badly infected iexploer.exe is missing its simply time to reinstall.  I mean you can try "sfc /scannow" and might get it to the point where the system is stable.  Don't understand why you can't simply transfer the 5-10MB file using any number of remote desktop programs that allow you to so do.

Comment: @Ramhound - fact is the connection is seriously intermittent. I am not entirely sure why, but I think it has got to do with interference over the Wireless High sites. About 50% packet loss.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 7 includes a version of the Powershell Console.  Here are the commands you need to download Chrome from Powershell:

```
$source = "https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid={8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}&amp;iid={A46431AA-136A-0ABB-2EFC-F03022606C71}&amp;lang=en&amp;browser=4&amp;usagestats=0&amp;appname=Google%2520Chrome&amp;needsadmin=prefers&amp;installdataindex=defaultbrowser/update2/installers/ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe"
$dest = [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Downloads\ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe")
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get Firefox via ftp as detailed in the answer from Mozilla Support to a similar question titled [How do I install Firefox on a computer with no current browser on it?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/964240)

Matt Silverman also describes doing this in [How To Download Firefox Without a Web Browser](http://www.mattsilverman.com/2009/06/how-to-download-firefox-without-a-web-browser.html).

In any case, the basic idea is, from the command line, to do the following:

```
ftp
open ftp.mozilla.org
username: anonymous
password: anonymous
cd pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/win32/en-US
ls
binary
lcd d:\folder (download destination)
get "Firefox Setup 22.0.exe"
(check that you have the Firefox Setup 22.0.exe file on the USB drive)
bye
```

Here's a recording of doing this in an actual session:

```
C:\>ftp
ftp> open ftp.mozilla.org
Connected to ftp.dynect.mozilla.net.
220-
220-   ftp.mozilla.org / archive.mozilla.org - files are in /pub/mozilla.org
220-
220-   Notice: This server is the only place to obtain nightly builds and needs to
220-   remain available to developers and testers. High bandwidth servers that
220-   contain the public release files are available at ftp://releases.mozilla.org/
220-   If you need to link to a public release, please link to the release server,
220-   not here. Thanks!
220-
220-   Attempts to download high traffic release files from this server will get a
220-   "550 Permission denied." response.
220
User (ftp.dynect.mozilla.net:(none)): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password: anonymous
230 Login successful.
ftp> cd pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/win32/en-US
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Here comes the directory listing.
Firefox Setup 24.0.exe
Firefox Setup Stub 24.0.exe
226 Directory send OK.
ftp: 53 bytes received in 0.02Seconds 3.31Kbytes/sec.
ftp> binary
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp> get "Firefox Setup 24.0.exe"
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for Firefox Setup 24.0.exe (22710720 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 22710720 bytes received in 137.84Seconds 164.76Kbytes/sec.
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.
C:\>
```

Afterwards, just run the `.exe` file downloaded to install the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [solution in Matt Silverman's blog](http://www.mattsilverman.com/2013/02/download-google-chrome-without-a-web-browser-using-windows-command-line.html), by running the following VBS script:

```
' This is the URL of the chrome EXE.
strFileURL="https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7BA024641A-81C0-533A-53CB-AE9534821219%7D%26lang%3Den%26browser%3D4%26usagestats3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dfalse%26installdataindex%3Ddefaultbrowser/update2/installers/ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe"
' This is where the file will download to.
strHDLocation = "c:\ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe"
' Fetch the file
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile
strHDLocation
Set objFSO = Nothing
objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Or you could use the command line `ftp.exe` and download a browser from an FTP server.

Comment: Please include essential parts of the linked solution in your answer. Links sometimes die, thus making an answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't transfer an installation file to the remote computer, you can maybe transfer a script that will download a file to a folder.

#### Download and install AutoHotkey

Visit http://www.autohotkey.com/ and install to your local computer.

#### Open Notepad and paste the following code

```
UrlDownloadToFile, http://www.your.download.url/installfile.exe, C:\installfile.exe
Run C:\installfile.exe
Exit
```

Save as DownloadBrowser.ahk.

#### Convert to exe and transfer to remote computer

Right click the file and select "Compile file", you'll get a DownloadBrowser.exe (it should e a few hundred KB). Execute the exe there. The browser installation should run automatically.